# ReferenceError: SGMax1 is not defined at eval (dashboard.v1.vue?88bf:1134) in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am using highcharts to display data from MySQL database using PHP.

here is my code

**CustomGauge.vue**

```
<template>
 <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";

 export default {
  name: "CustomGuage",
   components: {
   highcharts: Chart
 },
 props: [
"data",
"title",
"name",
"min",
"max",
"format",
"text",
"x",
"y",
"target",
"targetFormat"
],
data() {
return {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      type: "solidgauge",
      style: {
        fontFamily: "Segoe UI Light",
        fontSize: "22px"
      },


      marginBottom: 190
    },

    title: {
      text: this.title,
      align: "left"
    },

    pane: {
      center: ["50%", "85%"],
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      size: 200,
      background: {
        innerRadius: "60%",
        outerRadius: "100%",
        shape: "arc",
        backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2"
      }
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: this.max,
      stops: [
        [0.1, "#c00000"], // green
        [0.5, "#ffc000"], // yellow
        [0.9, "#4f6228"] // red
      ],
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickPositions: [0, this.max],
      title: {
        y: -70
      },
      labels: {
        y: 16
      }
    },

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          y: -1,
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: true
        }
      }
    },

    series: [
      {
        name: this.name,
        data: this.data,
        dataLabels: {
          format: this.format
        }
      },
      {
        data: this.target,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: this.targetFormat,
          verticalAlign: "top",
          borderWidth: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        },
        type: "gauge",
        dial: {
          baseLength: "100%",
          radius: "110%",
          rearLength: "-45%"
        }
      }
    ]
   }
  };
 },
};
```

I call it in my page like this

```
    <CustomGuage
        class="guage"
        :title="guageTitle1"
        :data="gaugeData1"
        :format="gaugeFormat2"
        :target="gaugeTarget1"
        :max="SGMax1"
        :targetFormat="targetFormat2"
      />
```

In the methods, i get the data from MySQL like this

```
 axios
    .get("http://localhost/intranet-php/SG1-max.php" + "?action=fetch-all")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      //var x = JSON.parse(response.data)
      var x = response.data;
      console.log( x);

      this.SGMax1.push(x);
      console.log(SGMax1);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I have even initialized it in **data()** like this -

```
SGMax1: [],
```

I get the error,
**ReferenceError: SGMax1 is not defined  at eval (dashboard.v1.vue?88bf:1134)**

I used the exact methods to get other data and it works fine. The php file also works fine as i can see the correct output in the console. Its only for this particular one i get the error. Am i defining it wrong in the chart component? Thanks for the help in advance